# Composing a Json in a Json for redux action

Tags: json, redux, action

I'm trying to create an action for redux by using an import from a different file, but something isn't working. It's easier to show the code:

In Api.js:

```
exopt const API =  {
  GET_LIST: {path: '/list', method: 'GET'},
  POST_LIST: {path: '/users/data', method: 'POST'}
};
```

In action.js:

```
import { API } from './Api';

export const fetchList = () => ({
  type: 'API_ACTION',
  payload: {
    API.GET_LIST
  }
)};
```

I would like fetchList to return the following action:

```
{
  type: 'API_ACTION',
  payload: {
    path: '/exercises/list',
    method: 'GET'
  }
}
```

But instead I'm getting an error:

```
Syntax error: ... Unexpected token, expected , (7:9)

   5 |   type: 'API_ACTION',
   6 |   payload: {
>  7 |      API.GET_LIST,
     |          ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set a key on an object without specifying a value.

Your `fetchList` in `action.js` should look like this instead:

```
export const fetchList = () => ({
  type: 'API_ACTION',
  payload: {
    path: API.GET_LIST.path,
    method: API.GET_LIST.method,
  },
)};
```

OR (even simpler)

```
export const fetchList = () => ({
  type: 'API_ACTION',
  payload: API.GET_LIST,
)};
```

There are many other ways to assign your payload (object spread, etc.), but the above should get you there.